# How to add google analytics in a react app without installing third party library? Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to add the piece of code google analytics gave me to a React app in the index.html. Is it possible or what can be done?

Comment: yeah, I would add the snippet in the index file, but if your app is a single page application, you'll need to keep track of your client-side route changes with javascript: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: i had a look at it but doesn't solve me problem unfortunately